# Creating a dynamic array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to create a dynamic array with a loop.. but I cant seem to get the desired results.

the array I want is:

```
{
    "CategoryName": "somecategoryname",
    "Date": "02-17-2012",
    "Id": 24,
    "ProductToHide": [
        {
            "IsHide": true,
            "ProductId": "someid"
        }
    ],
    "ProductsToAdd": [
        {
            "MealSequence": "S1",
            "ProductId": "Someid"
        },
        {
            "MealSequence": "S2",
            "ProductId": "Snack_11"
        }
    ],
    "UserId": "1"
}
```

and I am using the following function to add products:

```
addProduct: function(id){
        var tempArr = [];
        $.each(this.mCData.ChildCategories, function(i, item){
            $.each(item.PList, function(j, jsonPr){
                if (jsonPr.TID == id){
                    addProduct = new mealTypeProduct();
                    addProduct.data = jsonPr;
                    tempArr = addProduct.modifyProduct();
                }   
            })
        })

    //  queryStr = {"add" : tempArr};
    //  this.modificationArray.push(queryStr);
        this.modificationArray['add'].push(tempArr);    
        console.log(this.modificationArray);
    }
```

Its giving me the following error:

```
this.modificationArray.add.push is not a function
this.modificationArray['add'].push(tempArr);
```

the initializing is done in the following manner:

```
var mealType = {
    chosenDate: new Date(), tabViewHtml: '',
    modificationArray: [], saveArray: [],
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The array you want is not array. It is an object. What function `modifyProduct` does? What it returns? Does it return array? If it return scalar(or object) you are loosing tempArray. Need more info.

Comment: modifyProduct() returns another sub array..

Comment: please share the source array/object from which you are trying to make this. If possible please create http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
                tempArr = addProduct.modifyProduct();
```

**replaces** `tempArr` with a new value, so at the end of the `$.each` call it will have the value from the last matching product (which may not be an array) rather than being an array of all of them. If that is what you want then that's not a problem.

As to the actual error you quote: what type of thing is `this.modificationArray`? Does it have a member called `add`? Does that member have a `push()` function? Is it initialized properly, or is it left uninitialized? If the latter, then there's your problem: you need to initialize it before you can call `push()`.

UPDATE: If `this.modificationArray` is initialized as `[]`, as in the new sample code, then it is an array itself; it does not have an `add` member. The code should say `this.modificationArray.push(tempArr)`.

Alternatively, if you really do want an `add` member, then `this.modificationArray` should be initialized as `modificationArray : {add:[]}`

Comment: thats what i figured. how do i initalize it properly?